# Why are The Wild Swans by Andersen and The Six Swans by Grimm so similar to each other?

Tags: folk-tales

Why are [The Wild Swans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wild_Swans) by Andersen and [The Six Swans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Six_Swans) by Grimm so similar to each other?

Which one is more original?

Comment: You do realise neither of them created the story, that they only wrote down existing folktales? And many folktales have variants in many different cultures. Here's a bunch for just this story: http://www.surlalunefairytales.com/sixswans/other.html